# Getting data from Swapi API https://swapi.co/api/people/

Tags: javascript, api, cors, axios

I want to fetch the https://swapi.co/api/people/ all name and other detail but when I am using an axios call to get the data and I am getting `undefined` for all data but if want one name I am getting a CORS error in console.

```
let button = document.querySelector("#button");
let name = document.querySelector("#displayDetail");

function getDetail(){
  var apiURL="https://swapi.co/api/people";
  axios.get(apiURL).then(function(response){    
    showDetail(response.data);
  });    
}

function showDetail(data){
  name.innerText=data.name;
}    

button.addEventListener('click',getDetail);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON data from https://swapi.co/api/people doesn’t have a `name` member. Instead it has a `results` member that is an array of objects, each of which has a `name` member.

So you need to loop through that `data.results` array to get each `name`:

```js
function getDetail() {
  var apiURL = "https://swapi.co/api/people";
  axios.get(apiURL).then(function(response) {
    showDetail(response.data);
  });
}

function showDetail(data) {
  for (i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
    console.log(data.results[i].name);
  }
}
getDetail();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

But note: That API endpoint paginates the results; so to get all the names, check `data.next` to get the URL for the next page, then make a new request with that URL to get the next set of results:

```js
function getDetail(apiURL) {
  axios.get(apiURL).then(function(response) {
    showDetail(response.data);
  });
}

function showDetail(data) {
  for (i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
    names = names + data.results[i].name + "\n";
    // name1.innerText = name1.innerText + "\n" + data.results[i].name;
  }
  if (data.next) {
    getDetail(data.next);
  } else {
    console.log(names); // name1.innerText = names;
  }
}
var names = "";
getDetail("https://swapi.co/api/people");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you it worked .. but name1.innerText =data.results[i].name is show only one name in webpage but in console  data.results[i].name is showing 10 names.function showDetail(data){
  for (i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {


  name1.innerText= data.results[i].name;

    }


}

Comment: `name1.innerText =data.results[i].name` is only going to show one name, because each time you call that in a loop it’s going to overwrite `name1.innerText`, not append to it. So if you want `name1.innerText` to have the complete list of names, then you need to do create a `names` (or whatever) string and append the names to that, and then only when there is no more `data.next`, do `name1.innerText = names`. See the updated code snippet in the answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for an explanation of what to do when somebody answers a question for you at Stack Overflow. You don’t have enough reputation to upvote yet, but you do have enough reputation to accept answers by clicking on the check mark beside any answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. You should do that for any answers you get here that solve the problems in your questions. And you get 2 points added to your rep each time you accept an answer, so accepting correct answers also gets you closer to getting enough rep do other things (like upvote)

Comment: Alternatively, I guess you could just do `name1.innerText = name1.innerText + data.results[i].name` in a loop, which will each time take the existing content of `name1.innerText` and append `data.results[i].name` to it, and then write that back to `name1.innerText`. See the updated snippet.

Comment: but for film i need to hit another api  https://swapi.co/api/films/{id}) . how to get hit 2 api

Comment: For that you probably want to create a separate new question

Answer (score 1):

try with this
swapi.co/api/people/
change for
swapi.dev/api/people/

Answer (score 0):

All resources support a search parameter that filters the set of resources returned. This allows you to make queries like:

```
https://swapi.co/api/people/?search=r2d2
```

To see the set of search fields for each resource, check out the individual resource documentation.